# This page redirects me forwards when i press back, but not on chrome

Tags: firefox, redirect

I have no errors relevant to what's going on, but for some reason, whenever i press back on my site from certain pages, it redirects me forwards.

I'd appreciate any help in fixing this, without breaking any features on my site. I'm at a loss, and i don't even know where to start debugging.

http://heylookjagex.xyz/index.php

Edit: Scrolling also feels weird on chrome

Answer (score 1):

Couple of important things related to your issue:

1. I tested everything from my Chrome and I have no issues (so it's not strictly Chrome related).
2. I noticed that you have bad HTML encoding inside your page, for example you have  elements before  when rendering, you might want to check this out.

[image]

If I were debugging this I would **handle bad HTML code first**, and after that I would **test web site with different browsers AND devices**, in order to pinpoint the problem.

Hope this helps. I believe once you write correct HTML you shouldn't have any problems with this web site.

All best,

Comment: I believe i corrected the header, (this was because the page is assembled with PHP and some javascript we need for this page conflicts with MyBB features) I'm still getting redirect issues though.

Comment: @JaidenWatling According to the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fheylookjagex.xyz%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), you have 18 errors on the page. Do the problems persist when you correct all of them?

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem, there was a superfluous JS file causing it which i removed.